# How to save a script when it's detected that it was run?

Tags: python, shell, terminal, automation, config

I have a config script that I change the parameters to, I want to be able to archive the code every time that I run it so that I can refer back to it and see that on this specific date I had the parameters set in this specific way. I don't know what this would even be called, my google searches aren't coming close to what I need.

Where do I start in my investigation? Can I do this within the Python script or would it be in the terminal? But I want the detection that it was run to be done by itself, not by the person.

Comment: Do you edit the script to set the parameters, or do you pass them in on the command line?

Comment: I edit the script to set the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your script could copy itself every time it is run by adding a few lines of code like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

from shutil import copyfile

copyfile(__file__, '%s.%d' % (__file__, time.time()))
```

`__file__` is the path to the current file. This code creates a copy of the file in the same directory as the original, appending the current epoch time to the filename.